# Viewpager и поворот экрана

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Добрый день!

Попытался найти ответ на свой вопрос на этом сайте, но так и не смог. 
Суть проблемы заключается в чем:
1) Имеется фрагмент, который объявлен в layout.

```
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frame_page"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.vonegosh.creditcalc.PageFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/pageview">
        </fragment>
```

2) Имеется класс PageFragment, который содержит в себе ViewPager и FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Выглядит это все примерно так:

```
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment {


    ViewPager mViewPager;
    View v;
    SharPref sharPref;
    private static final String VIEW_PAGER_POSITION = "ViewPagerPosition";
    TitleAdapter titleAdapter;

    public void setAdapter(Calc calc) {
        if (titleAdapter == null) {
            titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getFragmentManager(), calc, getActivity());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        } else {
            titleAdapter.updateAdapter(calc);
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(sharPref.getSharedPreferences().getInt(VIEW_PAGER_POSITION, 0));
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pageview, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerTabStrip strip = (PagerTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
        strip.setTabIndicatorColor(0x228B22);
        ((ViewPager.LayoutParams) (v.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip)).getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        sharPref = new SharPref(getActivity());
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                sharPref.getEditor().putInt(VIEW_PAGER_POSITION, position).commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    class TitleAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Bundle b;
        String[] titles;
        Calc calc;
        FragmentView1 fragmentView1;
        FragmentView2 fragmentView2;
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm;
        TitleAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, Calc calc, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.titles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.данные_для_pageview);
            this.fm = fm;
            fragmentView1 = new FragmentView1();
            fragmentView2 = new FragmentView2();
            b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable("calc", calc);
        }

        void updateAdapter(Calc calc) {
            this.calc = calc;
           // ((FragmentView1) fm.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + 0)).updateAdapter(calc);
           fragmentView1.updateAdapter(calc);
           // fragmentView2.updateAdapter(calc);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragmentView1.setArguments(b);
                    return fragmentView1;
                case 1:
                    fragmentView2.setArguments(b);
                    return fragmentView2;
                case 2:
                    FragmentView3 fragmentView3 = new FragmentView3();
                    fragmentView3.setArguments(b);
                    return fragmentView3;
                case 3:
                    FragmentView4 fragmentView4 = new FragmentView4();
                    fragmentView4.setArguments(b);
                    return fragmentView4;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3)  Через процедуру  `public void setAdapter(Calc calc)` активити передает фрагменту информацию, после чего он либо создает адаптер для viewPager либо обновляет адаптер, если он уже есть.

```
public void setAdapter(Calc calc) {
        if (titleAdapter == null) {
            titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getFragmentManager(), calc, getActivity());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        } else {
            titleAdapter.updateAdapter(calc);
        }
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(sharPref.getSharedPreferences().getInt(VIEW_PAGER_POSITION, 0));
    }
```

4. Когда создается TitleAdapter, информация упаковывается в Bundle и передается через setArgument в дочерние фрагменты. Когда обновляется TitleAdapter, мы передаем дочернему фрагменту через процедуру updateAdapter экземпляр класса Calc, после чего дочерний фрагмент FragmentView1 обновляет adapter ListView.

В штатном режиме всё работает идеально. Теперь переворачиваем экран. Не важно сколько раз. TitleAdapter пересоздался. Попытаемся передать данные Calc еще раз. Так как адаптер TitleAdapter уже существует, отрабатывает ветка программы на обновление дочерних фрагментов и программа выбивает с ошибкой NullPointExceprion. В итоге получается, что фрагмент как бы пересоздался, но в нем getActivity как и другие ссылки на такие элементы как listView потеряены и ссылаются на Null. 
Вся эта идея с обновлениями заключается в том, чтобы вызывать notifyDataSetChanged у адаптера ListView в дочерних фрагментах, когда этот адаптер уже существует. Но после поворота экрана этот адаптер возвращает Null, хотя в интерфейсе все визуально пересоздалось.

UPD: Разобрался в чем проблема. Дело в том, что каким-то образом FragmentStatePagerAdapter сохраняет состояние фрагментов, несмотря на то, что вызывается новый адаптер. Или я не так понял. Но вот этот код в мне помог `@Override public Parcelable saveState() {
 return null; 
}`

Answer (score 1):

в `onCreateView()` напишите `setRetainInstance(true)`

Comment: во фрагменте PageView  или в дочерних?

Comment: можете во всех - хуже не станет. Этот метод сохраняет состояние фрагмента, разрушая лишь его оболочку, после поворота экрана он возвращает исходное состояние и таким образом, можно сказать, поворот будет обработан.

Comment: добавил во всех,при повороте теперь ошибку не выдает, но интерфейс теперь пустой. Как будто ViewPager'у не передавали адаптер TitleAdapter.